# Array.join() functionality with JQuery elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an element created that I append various children to. They are not all similar in any selector necessarily, but they are all direct children.

I'd like to insert an element between them to unify them with "and", but I'm spacing on how I could do that.

For instance;

```html
<div id="parent">
   <span>This sentence is one</span>
   <span>this sentence is another</span>
</div>
```

should more resemble

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span>This sentence is one</span>
  <span>&nbsp;and&nbsp;</span>
  <span>this sentence is another</span>
</div>
```

All are children of the top level `div` but some may be a `span` while others an `a`. I cannot add a class nor ID to them. There is also an unknown amount of children, only certain there are more than 2.

My idea was to get the children of the `parent` div & then use `.join("&nbsp;and&nbsp;")` but I can't seem to find a cohesive way to do so. Does similar logic exist? I'd have scrubbed docs a bit more, but they seem to be having some slowness issues today.

Comment: insert after and insert before both can serve this purpose, depending on whether you want to omit the first child or the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.after()` to add the span after each child except the last one. Use `.slice()` to select that range of children.

```js
let children = $("#parent").children();
children.slice(0, -1).after('<span>&nbsp;and&nbsp;</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
   <span>This sentence is one</span>
   <span>this sentence is another</span>
   <span>this sentence is third</span>
</div>
```